# Using variables in Tcl REST's config array of dicts

Tags: arrays, rest, dictionary, tcl

How can I use a variable that is comprised of two whitespace-separated strings in the interface definition variable for tcllib's [rest package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-19/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/rest/rest.html)?

The interface usage specifies an array of REST call definitions, which are themselves dictionaries.

In the case of this particular API, I need to pass in the auth token that was retrieved from a previous call. How do I use that value as a variable when defining the configuration array?

```
set token "Token "
append token 123456789ABCD

array set restApi {
    callFoo {
        url http://example.com/foo
        method get
        format json
        headers {Auth $token}
   }
}
rest::create_interface restApi
set resultDict [restApi::callFoo]
```

`headers {Auth $token}` and `headers "Auth $token"` both result in a literal `Auth: $token` header being sent. Likewise, `headers {Auth [set token]}` sends `Auth: [set token]`.

It doesn't appear that variable in the array definition are interpolated, which is not entirely unexpected given the standard behavior of braces, although they're commonly used to group multi-dimensional dicts.

Putting quotes around `$token` in the dict (`headers Auth "$token"`) does interpolate, but I get the following error.

```
missing value to go with key
    while executing
"dict for {k val} [dict get $config headers] {
            _addopts $val config
        }"
(procedure "rest::create_interface" line 36)
invoked from within
"rest::create_interface restApi"
(file "t.tcl" line 86)
```

Originally I thought that the odd number of words in the $headers dict is breaking the `dict for`. But removing the whitespace from `$token` doesn't change the error.

Setting the value outside of the config array results in the same error:

```
dict set restApi(callFoo) headers "Auth $token"
```

I'm at a loss. Please help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope!

Comment: Your example is broken, the `[array set]` is not correct, to begin with (unbalanced braces). Pls post exactly the code that you are trying to run. When corrected, the snippet runs just fine with my `rest` installation (version 1.3.1).

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect code that better explains the problem. Note that in some of the variations, the code will indeed run, but sends a header string that is not interpolated.

Comment: Tip: print the value of restApi(callFoo). You'll see the string indicating the value of key `header` is `Auth` and there is a trailing key `$token` without value. Using `dict set restApi(callFoo) headers "Auth {$token}"` will probably work.

Comment: When substitutions with double quotes get hard because of whitespaces etc I fallback to commands such as `list` and `subst`. E.g. "Auth $token" -> [list Auth $token]. Less error prone.

Comment: Thanks, @Andreas - you pointed me in the right direction. I submitted my own answer based on your suggestions, with some added clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATED 11/30/2019

It turns out the implementation includes the ability to embed variables in the config dict by wrapping the variable name with `%`. The value of the variable can be set as an option to the function:

```
array set restApi {
    callFoo {
        url http://example.com/foo
        method get
        format json
        headers "Auth %tokenVar%"
    }
}

rest::create_interface restApi
restApi::callFoo -tokenVar $token
```

It should also be noted that the package permits these variables to be set prior to the call:

```
restApi::set_static_args tokenVar $token
restApi::callFoo
```

Variables set in this way are applied to all defined REST calls. So if multiple calls require the `Auth` header, simply add the `headers "Auth %tokenVar%` to the config for each call.

### Previous answer, saved for posterity

Thanks to Andreas, who hit on the answer. Setting the headers dict with the following syntax works:

```
array set restApi {
    callFoo {
        url http://example.com/foo
        method get
        format json
    }
}

dict set restApi(callFoo) headers [list Auth $token]
```

This also works:

```
array set restApi {
    callFoo {
        url http://example.com/foo
        method get
        format json
        headers [list Auth $token]
    }
}

set restApi(callFoo) [subst $restApi(callFoo)]
```

The latter form is probably more flexible, as one can use multiple variables in the array definition, and prior to the `rest::create_interface` call, loop through each element and perform the `subst`.

For posterity's sake, I'll note that I may have tried the first approach at one point, but because I had "commented out" some of my failed attempts at defining the headers dict in the restApi array definition, it "broke" the array. That's because the parser didn't interpret the `#headers` *line* as a comment, but rather the *string* `#headers` was interpreted as a dict key.

Comment: Note how the content of `token` may still break the code if containing braces, e.g. `set token "hello} {world"`. Using the list command `[list Auth $token]` is really the best choice when the substituted value MUST be a list of a certain length. Whereas double quotes is best only used for plain strings.

Comment: Updated the answer to use the `[list Auth $token]` as per @Andreas suggestion